# Multiple forms in same page with check boxes in that only one form is working remaining forms not working

Tags: html, checkbox

Here is the link to the page with different forms, http://hamzakhan.name/dev/eric/options/five/fiveactivities.html. As you can see, the first form with checkboxes works, but on the other forms, as you click on the checkboxes, only the first form works.

I tried to search for answers on that and all I could find was a subject talking about different things, something about submit forms, etc. I just couldn't find anything related to what I was looking for on why the same forms on one page are not working independently of each other.

I also tried to write the javascript code for that but it's not working.

Here's the html code

```
<div class="activitiesform">
   <form>
     <div class="activitiesfield1">
       <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="activities1" class="activitiescb"/><label for="activities1"></label>
     </div>
     <div class="activitiesfield2">
       <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="activities2" class="activitiescb"/><label for="activities2"></label>
     </div>
     <div class="activitiesfield3">
       <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="activities3" class="activitiescb"/><label for="activities3"></label>
     </div>
     <div class="activitiesfield4">
       <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="activities4" class="activitiescb"/><label for="activities4"></label>
     </div>
     <div class="activitiesfield5">  
      <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="activities5" class="activitiescb"/><label for="activities5"></label>
     </div>
     <div class="activitiesfield6">
       <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="activities6" class="activitiescb"/><label for="activities6"></label>
     </div>
     <div class="activitiesfield7">
       <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="activities7" class="activitiescb"/><label for="activities7"></label>
     </div>
     <div class="activitiesfield8">
       <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="activities8" class="activitiescb"/><label for="activities8"></label>
     </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

And this is javascript code

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.activitiescb').on('change', function() {
        this.checked = true;
        $(this).closest('form').find('.activitiescb').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
</script>
```

I really need to get better at Javascript. I'm good with html and css, but sucks at Javascript, but I do know few things but apparently, not enough...

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context, that's the basis

Comment: your class activitiescb is same for all checkbox, make them unique for each form. Lets see it works or not.

Comment: Why are you recreating radio buttons? Why are you always setting it to true onchange?

Comment: hey @kristina you need only one activity should be allowed to selected in 1st dog and same for others also?

Comment: I don't know what you mean but I do want the checkboxes to work independently in each form. If you click on the other forms beside the first form in 1st dog, the checkboxes show up only in the first form.

Comment: Are you asking if only one checkbox checked is allow on each form? No, I want the user to click on any checkbox in each form for each dog.

Comment: I have updated forms replace with your forms appropriately and let me know. Whether its working or not mostly probably it will work because i tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID is the only reason because of which your clicks are not working except first one.

Then try to differenciate the forms by giving ids & names to forms so that it will seperated. Always keep in mind that ID is the unique key to catch that entity in the entire page. Which means id should be unique to entire DOM. If its repeated then only one of the id is others will not work.

For reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp

I have updated your code please check and replace with your code Okay,

```
<!-- form one starts -->
<form id="activitiesform1">
    <div class="activitiesfield1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="firstdog_activity1" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="firstdog_activity1"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="firstdog_activity2" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="firstdog_activity2"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="firstdog_activity3" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="firstdog_activity3"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="firstdog_activity4" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="firstdog_activity4"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield5">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="firstdog_activity5" class="activitiescb"><label for="firstdog_activity5"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="firstdog_activity6" class="activitiescb"><label for="firstdog_activity6"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield7">
    <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="firstdog_activity7" class="activitiescb"><label for="firstdog_activity7"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield8">
    <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="firstdog_activity8" class="activitiescb"><label for="firstdog_activity8"></label>
    </div>
</form>
<!-- form one ends -->

<!-- form two starts -->
<form id="activitiesform2">
    <div class="activitiesfield1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="seconddog_activity1" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="seconddog_activity1"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="seconddog_activity2" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="seconddog_activity2"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="seconddog_activity3" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="seconddog_activity3"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="seconddog_activity4" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="seconddog_activity4"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield5">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="seconddog_activity5" class="activitiescb"><label for="seconddog_activity5"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="seconddog_activity6" class="activitiescb"><label for="seconddog_activity6"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield7">
    <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="seconddog_activity7" class="activitiescb"><label for="seconddog_activity7"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield8">
    <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="seconddog_activity8" class="activitiescb"><label for="seconddog_activity8"></label>
    </div>
</form>
<!-- form two ends -->

<!-- form three starts -->
<form id="activitiesform3">
    <div class="activitiesfield1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="thirddog_activity1" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="thirddog_activity1"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="thirddog_activity2" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="thirddog_activity2"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="thirddog_activity3" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="thirddog_activity3"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="thirddog_activity4" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="thirddog_activity4"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield5">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="thirddog_activity5" class="activitiescb"><label for="thirddog_activity5"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="thirddog_activity6" class="activitiescb"><label for="thirddog_activity6"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield7">
    <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="thirddog_activity7" class="activitiescb"><label for="thirddog_activity7"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield8">
    <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="thirddog_activity8" class="activitiescb"><label for="thirddog_activity8"></label>
    </div>
</form>
<!-- form three ends -->

<!-- form four starts -->
<form id="activitiesform4">
    <div class="activitiesfield1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="forthdog_activity1" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="forthdog_activity1"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="forthdog_activity2" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="forthdog_activity2"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="forthdog_activity3" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="forthdog_activity3"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="forthdog_activity4" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="forthdog_activity4"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield5">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="forthdog_activity5" class="activitiescb"><label for="forthdog_activity5"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="forthdog_activity6" class="activitiescb"><label for="forthdog_activity6"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield7">
    <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="forthdog_activity7" class="activitiescb"><label for="forthdog_activity7"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield8">
    <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="forthdog_activity8" class="activitiescb"><label for="forthdog_activity8"></label>
    </div>
</form>
<!-- form four ends -->

<!-- form five starts -->
<form id="activitiesform5">
    <div class="activitiesfield1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="fifthdog_activity1" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="fifthdog_activity1"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="fifthdog_activity2" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="fifthdog_activity2"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="fifthdog_activity3" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="fifthdog_activity3"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="fifthdog_activity4" class="activitiescb">
        <label for="fifthdog_activity4"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield5">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="fifthdog_activity5" class="activitiescb"><label for="fifthdog_activity5"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="fifthdog_activity6" class="activitiescb"><label for="fifthdog_activity6"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield7">
    <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="fifthdog_activity7" class="activitiescb"><label for="fifthdog_activity7"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="activitiesfield8">
    <input type="checkbox" name="activitiescb" value="activities" id="fifthdog_activity8" class="activitiescb"><label for="fifthdog_activity8"></label>
    </div>
</form>
<!-- form five ends -->
```

Comment: Okay, so I gave each form an different id. What will the javascript code be?
Is this the function?
$function myform () {
document.getElementById("activitiesform1,activitiesform2,activitiesform3,activitiesform4,activitiesform5").id = "myform";
}

Comment: @KristinaBressler give me 2 mins i'll review your code completely and just update you.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works now! So the difference isn't in the form id, but in the checkbox id, right? And I don't need javascript to fix anything too.

Comment: Yeah you are right :) Always remember id should be unique in the entire page Okay. And thanks for marked as answer :D All the best wishes study well. I saw your portfolios things are good. Keep going. Have nice day.

Comment: Thanks, I need all the luck because this page is going to be a part of many html pages I've done in order to put everything in Angular JS and that's my first time coding everything in Angular JS...

Thank you for commenting on my portfolio. I still need to redesign my portfolio soon. You can check out my re-design wireframes at https://www.behance.net/kikidesign/wip

Comment: @KristinaBressler You are most welcome. I really appreciate your efforts. You are graphic designer even though you trying to learn Angular JS really inspired. I saw your behance profile. As I already told you, you are doing really good. You have surely a better future. Congrats! and hearty wishes for your goals.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see what you are doing `onChange` is you're setting the current checkbox to `checked` and take all other checkboxes in the form and set them to `unchecked`, which is the behaviour of a radio button group. If you want to get just basic checkbox behaviour where multiple can be `checked` or `unchecked` you could do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.activitiescb').on('change', function() {
        if (this.checked)
             !this.checked;
        else
             this.checked;
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see the purpose of this snippet. But good point regarding radio buttons

Comment: um, and what is `this.checked;` supposed to do?

Comment: it sets the checked status of the checkbox to true

Comment: I'm so sorry. It's not working. I'm not good at writing javascript functions. I only thought that the code will work. I only wanted the checkboxes on other forms to work, not just the first form. Therefore, I wanted to write a function that will make each form act independently of each other.